# How to perform Pagination in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pagination, flutter-layout

I have been going through various articles on pagination in flutter but none of them seem to work out for me. The API endpoint I am working with looks like this
http://camx.heropp.com/api/connect?offset=0 (this is an example link and so it won't work) while the response I get when I make the request looks like this

```
{
    "result": {
        "connectUsers": [
            {
                "_id": "5f6a412d2ea9350017bec99f",
                "userProfile": {
                    "rep_points": 0.75,
                    "visits": 0,
                    "bio": "Nothing for you ",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "university": "University Of Technology",
                    "avatar": "https://camx.heroapp.com/5f6a412d2ea9350017bec99f"
                },
                "name": "Joseph Henshaw ",
                "userTag": "bigjo",
                "id": "5f6a412d2ea9350017bec99f",
                "sameCampus": true
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f6bbf1cbd5faa00170d92b1",
                "userProfile": {
                    "rep_points": 0,
                    "visits": 0
                },
                "name": "John Doe",
                "userTag": "@doee",
                "id": "5f6bbf1cbd5faa00170d92b1",
                "sameCampus": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

what i am trying to achieve is paginate the data coming from the api..the offset begins at 0 and increases with 10, i.e to get more data 0ffset=20..30..and so on

This is the request I am making to get the JSON response shown above

```dart
Future<void> fetchConnect() async {
    var uri = Uri.parse('http://campusx.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/connect');
    uri = uri.replace(query: 'offset=$offsetNumber');
    print(uri);
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        uri,
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $userToken",
        },

      );
      // List<Photo> fetchedPhotos = Photo.parseList(json.decode(response.body));
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
         print("IT works")
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
      List<ConnectUsers> fetchedConnects =
          ConnectUsers.parseList(json.decode(response.body));
      setState(() {
        connectMore = fetchedConnects.length == defaultConnectsPerPageCount;
        loading = false;
        offsetNumber = offsetNumber + 10;
        connects.addAll(fetchedConnects);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
        error = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

and this is how my UI for displaying the data fetched(the widget getConnect is placed in the body of my Scaffold

```dart
 Widget getConnects() {
    if (connects.isEmpty) {
      if (loading) {
        return Center(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ));
      } else if (error) {
        return Center(
            child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              loading = true;
              error = false;
              fetchConnects();
            });
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Text("Error while loading connects, tap to try again"),
          ),
        ));
      }
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: connects.length + (connectMore ? 10 : 0),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == connects.length - nextPageThreshold) {
              fetchConnects();
            }
            if (index == connects.length) {
              if (error) {
                return Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      loading = true;
                      error = false;
                      fetchConnects();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child:
                        Text("Error while loading connects, tap to try agin"),
                  ),
                ));
              } else {
                return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ));
              }
            }
            // final Photo photo = photos[index];
            final ConnectUsers connect = connects[index];
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Image.network(
                  //   connect.name.connectUsers[index].userProfile.avatar,
                  //   fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  //   width: double.infinity,
                  //   height: 160,
                  // ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Text(connect.name,
                        // connect
                        // .result.connectUsers[index].userProfile.university,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
    }
    return Container();
  }
```

this is the error i get when using this code

```
The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEmpty
```

Comment: So what *exactly* are you having problems with? Do you get errors?

Comment: @nvoigt yes i do get errors, one method i tried kept telling me connectUsers was called on null, another just kept the circular progress indicator showing while increasing the offset value in my debug console and making the request over and over

Comment: Well, you will have to post that code for us to find the mistakes. We cannot possibly advise you on code we have not seen.

Comment: You should post your code and precise errors so somebody to be able to help you.

Comment: @nvoigt  I have added my code and the error encountered

Comment: This is the link to the article which i used to get what i wrote  https://medium.com/@sharmadhiraj.np/infinite-scrolling-listview-on-flutter-88d7a5e2bb4

Comment: @ChessMax  code and error encountered added

Comment: Looks like you are calling `connects.isEmpty` in your widget but you didn't initialize connects -> connects is null so you get the error above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I've solved the problem, this is the way i used

### this is my model.dart class

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

ConnectModel payloadFromJson(String str) =>
    ConnectModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(ConnectModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ConnectModel {
  ConnectModel({
    this.result,
  });

  Result result;

  factory ConnectModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ConnectModel(
        result: Result.fromJson(json["result"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "result": result.toJson(),
      };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    this.connect,
  });

  List<Connect> connect;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        connect: List<Connect>.from(
            json["connectUsers"].map((x) => Connect.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "connectUsers": List<dynamic>.from(connect.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Connect with ChangeNotifier {
  Connect({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.userTag,
    this.university,
    this.checkIsFollowing,
    this.avatar,
  });
  String name;
  String userTag;
  String id;
  String university;
  String avatar;
  bool checkIsFollowing;

  factory Connect.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Connect(
        id: json["_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        userTag: json["userTag"],
        university: json["userProfile"]["university"],
        checkIsFollowing: json["checkIsFollowing"],
        avatar: json["userProfile"]["avatar"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "name": name,
        "userTag": userTag,
        "userProfile"
            "university": university,
        "userProfile"
            "avatar": avatar,
        "checkIsFollowing": checkIsFollowing
      };
}
```

this is my method, where offsetNumber is initialized to 0 by default

```
  List<Connect> mainList = [];
  List<String> nameList = [];
  Future<List<Connect>> getConnectionsList(var offsetNumber) async {
    var uri = "http://campusx.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/connect?$offsetNumber";
    var token = "pass_your_token_here";
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get(uri, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"});
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        var d = data['result']['connectUsers'];
        for (var u in d) {
          Connect c = Connect.fromJson(u);
          mainList.add(c);
        }
        setState(() {
          nameList = mainList.map((e) => e.name).toList();
          //add other parameters gotten from the endpoint here, i used name only for test purposes
        });
      } else {
        print(response.body);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return mainList;
  }
```

this is the ListView builder i displayed the names in

```
     ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mainList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Container(
              height: 120,
              child: Text(
                nameList[index],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 39),
               ),
            );
          },
       )
```

then either onClick or a button or when the list hits the bottom of your phone screen, you'd setState  (() {}); and increase the size of the offsetNumber. Something like this:

```
setState(() {
  offsetNumber = offsetNumber + 10;
  future = getConnectionsList(offsetNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are calling connects.isEmpty in your widget but you didn't initialise connects -> connects is null so you get the error above.
You could do a null check or initialise connects

```dart
...
// initialise so connects is not null
connects = []
...
 Widget getConnects() {
    if (connects.isEmpty) {
      if (loading) {
        return Center(
(...)
```

```dart
 Widget getConnects() {
// do a null check before calling member
    if (connects == null || connects.isEmpty) {
      if (loading) {
        return Center(
(...)
```

Comment: I think a safer and cleaner way would be if (connects?.isEmpty??false) ... I never trust checking for null and checking for a value on the object on the same if..

Comment: I feel you, but in dart boolean expressions terminate as soon as the outcome has been decided - I wasn't sure about it so I started a new project and tested all the relevant combinations. That gave me a lot more confidence in my understanding of the language. - Btw you would need to return true not false if it's null.